# Implementation of nested for loops in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, rdd, nested-loops

I am new to PySpark and I am trying to understand how can we write multiple nested for loop in PySpark, I go through some of the existing questions asked but didn't solve my problem. Any help will be appreciated

FB is a pyspark RDD containing 200 columns and 06 rows and delay is a list of values calculated in previous step. 
If it is needed it I will provide.

```
  s2=[ ['0' for col in range(100)]  for row in range(100)]
  for u in log_progress (range(100)):
      for v in log_progress (range(100)):
          energy=0.0
          for h in log_progress(range(200)):
              z=0.0
              for l in log_progress(range(6)):
                  if h+delay[l][u][v] < 100:
                     m= int(h+delay[l][u][v])
                     z= z + float(str(FB.collect()[l][m]))
                 energy= energy+z*z
    s2[u][v]=round(energy)
```

When debugging the code the value of energy is calculated correctly however it takes a long time to write the values to s2. My question is there any alternative to do it.

Comment: What does your `log_progress()` function do?

Comment: It just track the progress of for loop. you may ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of your nested for loops will be called a total of: 
`100*100*200*6 = 12,000,000` times, you can either make each calculation more efficient or do these calculations fewer times.  I have an idea to reduce the number of calculations you must do.

The way you have this calculation set up, I think you can more efficiently deal with your `h` variable.  Instead of looping through all 200 options with range you can build only the values of h that satisfy your condition `if h+delay[l][u][v]< 100:` and knowing what `delay[l][u][v]` is already (by looping over `l,u,v` before `h`) we can define a specific range of `h` values we want to loop over with `for h in log_progress(range(0,int(100-delay[l][u][v])))`.

It appears that in many cases you will only have a few `h` values that impact your solution, the rest being omitted via `if h+delay[l][u][v]< 100:`, so omitting those options from the start might speed your code up.  The below should do as I described:

```
  s2=[ ['0' for col in range(100)]  for row in range(100)]
  for u in log_progress (range(100)):
      for v in log_progress (range(100)):
          energy=0.0
          #for h in log_progress(range(200)):
          z=0.0
          for l in log_progress(range(6)):
              for h in log_progress(range(0,int(100-delay[l][u][v]))):
              #if h+delay[l][u][v]< 100:
                 m= int(h+delay[l][u][v])
                 z= z + float(str(FB.collect()[l][m]))
              energy= energy+z*z
    s2[u][v]=round(energy)
```

This should get you somewhere between 200 times and absolutely no speedup, depending on what your `delay[l][u][v]` data looks.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response, I have tried this solution and it works fine however my aim is to speedup the process.  delay is a list of int values created as "delay = [[ ['0' for col in range(100)] for col in range(100)] for row in range(6)]" . i am unable to post the complete code in the comments however the code for it works fine.